# How to add a clickable image (company logo) on OpenLayer maps in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, dictionary, openlayers

I want to add bunch of images on the top of the "OpenLayer" map, implemented in a vue.js project and would like to direct users to the company's website by clicking on the logo (image). The map is already set, but I have no idea how to add the CLICKABLE logo image on top of it.
Thank you for your support.

Comment: Custom control?  https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/custom-controls.html

Comment: If your image must be displayed at a specific coordinate, you can see how to add an image and make it clickable  in this example: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/icon.html

Comment: @otrreal Thank you for your message, I wonder if I can find any source to link my logo images to a certain URL, like company's custom website. Thank you